# Remove element from a sublist to a list

Tags: java, arraylist

We take a list and a sublist to seek into list.
I want to remove on list the first apparition of sublist if it is on list.

Here is an example of what i want:

```
removeSubList([3,2,3,4,5,3],[3])  [2,3,4,5,3] 
removeSubList([2,3,4,5,3,4],[3,4])  [2,5,3,4] 
removeSubList([3,2,3,4,7],[3,7])  [2,3,4] 
removeSubList([3,2,3,4,5,3],[])  [3,2,3,4,5,3] 
removeSubList([],[3,7])  [] 
removeSubList(null,[3,7])  null 
removeSubList([3,2,3,4,5,3],null)  [3,2,3,4,5,3]
```

And here is my code what i tried but it doesn't work...

```
public class RemovePositionList<E> {

/**
 * Returns in "list" the previous content of "list" after removing "subList" if it is present in "list"
 *
 * @param  list     (input/output)  The list where search and remove the first occurrence of "subList"
 * @param  subList  (input)         The sub list to search within "list"
 */

public void removeSubList(PositionList<E> list,PositionList<E> subList) {
    Position<E> cursor = list.first();
    Position<E> cursor2 = subList.first();
    while(cursor != null && cursor2 != null){  //comprobamos que ningun elemento es null
        if(cursor.element().equals(cursor2)){
            list.remove(cursor);
        }
        else{
            list.next(cursor);
            list.next(cursor2);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for help...

Comment: What's Position and PositionList? Are you writing your own kind of iterators?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm correct but I think the error is in the `if()` condition instead of

```
if(cursor.element().equals(cursor2))
```

shouldn't it be

```
if(cursor.element().equals(cursor2.element()))
```

..............:)

Comment: not works... that error: java.lang.NullPointerException
**** Error detected
 at removeSubList.RemovePositionList.removeSubList(RemovePositionList.java:22)
 at removeSubList.ListUtils.do_check(Tester.java:306)
 at removeSubList.Tester.main(Tester.java:42)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: wrong result.
 at removeSubList.ListUtils.do_check(Tester.java:345)
 at removeSubList.Tester.main(Tester.java:42)

Comment: When ever you get a nullPointerException it means that you haven't initialized de object or in other words the object is null so check you code and find if you didn't leave an object as null this is an example:  Test test1; but if you didnt initialized it test1 would be null so you should try something like this :) :  Test test1 = new Test();

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach making for the sample input you provided. It holds for all cases.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer listElements[] = {3,2,3,4,7};
    Integer subListElements[] = {3,7};

    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(listElements));
    List<Integer> subList = Arrays.asList(subListElements);
    System.out.println(removeSubList(list, subList));
}

private static List<Integer> removeSubList(List<Integer> list, List<Integer> subList){
    if(list == null || list.isEmpty() || subList == null){
        return list;
    }
    for(Integer item : subList){
        list.remove(item);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: can i do it without iterators?